# Every open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ have same cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ (Assumption checking)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove every (non-empty) open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$

I hope this question hasn’t been asked before
I see it has for functions and in a limited
form.

So these are the subsets of R
$(-\infty, a), (\infty, b)$ and $(a,b)$
and   lastly $(-\infty,\infty)$

So to show these subsets have same cardinality

1. Create bijections between R and each
   subinterval eg, $f:(0,1)\mapsto(a,b)$
   and $f:(a,b)\mapsto(0,1)$
2. Use Schroeder-Bernstein theorem for rest

Another way is to do it is to use the theorem

**1.3 Theorem**
(a)
The union of any collection of open subsets of the real line is an open subset of the real line

(2) Knowing $|(0,1)|=\mathfrak{c}$ and Theorem 1.3.a is
true then $(-\infty,a) \cup (a,b) \cup
(b,\infty)$ is true by 1.3.a so can we conclude thier subsets have $\mathfrak{c}$?
(I didn’t invoke a bijection, in this option,
is it still needed? Probably.)
This option seems to naive for me.

Source: Conover Robert: First Course in Topology, Ex. 4.5.1
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Let me rephrase the question as every non-empty open set in $\mathbb R$ has cardinality $c$. Note that $\emptyset$ (empty set) is open in $\mathbb R$ but has cardinality $0$.

Comment: So these intervals have same cardinality as (0,1)

Comment: Every non-empty open subset contains an open interval $(a,b)$ so if $|(a,b)|=\mathfrak{c}$, the same is true of any open subset $U$, since $\mathfrak{c}=|(a,b)|\leq |U|\leq|\mathbb{R}|=\mathfrak{c}$

Comment: Nice and simple . l like it